# Botframework speech ignore url

Tags: c#, botframework, text-to-speech

I am working on a bot which simulates a service desk. One it's services is replying to FAQs, sometimes by giving the user links to sites/documents in SharePoint, payroll login, etc.

When using text-to-speech for the responses, the bot reads out the entire url including `https://` and the request parameters.

Is there any way to normalize the urls or remove them entirely from the bot's speech responses?

The links are coming primarily from QnAMaker answers, and some hard coded URLs both of which are encoded either as `<a href=...>` tags or `[Example website](example.com)` markdown style links.

Comment: What is it reading, a HTML file?

Comment: @SteveJ updated the question with information about the links

Comment: Hmm. Not sure about with markdown, but HTML tags have the `alt` tag to hint to screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to normalize the urls or remove them entirely from the bot's speech responses?

You can try to match&replace  tag/markdown link with the text of that link by using regular expression, and then specify the text to be spoken. The following sample code work for me, please refer to it.

```
var qna_answer = "please check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com)";

//var qna_answer = "please check <a href='https://learn.microsoft.com'>this documentation</a>";

string innertxt, res = "";

if (Regex.Match(qna_answer, @"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>").Success)
{
        innertxt =Regex.Match(qna_answer, @"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>").Groups[1].Value;

        res = Regex.Replace(qna_answer, @"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>", innertxt);
}
else if (Regex.Match(qna_answer, @"\[([^]]*)\]\(([^\s^\)]*)[\s\)]").Success)
{
    innertxt = Regex.Match(qna_answer, @"\[([^]]*)\]\(([^\s^\)]*)[\s\)]").Groups[1].Value;

    res = Regex.Replace(qna_answer, @"\[([^]]*)\]\(([^\s^\)]*)[\s\)]", innertxt);
}


await context.SayAsync(text: $"{qna_answer}", speak: $"{res}");
```

*Test result:*

[image]